# Android simple JsonObjectRequest throwing null exception

Tags: android, android-studio

Trying to make an api call to a link :

```
http://192.168.1.13/backendapi/api/api.php?apicall=getsale
```

This works as planned trough POSTMAN and returns JSON as response with list of an objects.

But when i try to make a call through android app with this code

```
String apiURL = "http://192.168.1.13/backendapi/api/api.php?apicall=getsale";

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, apiURL,null   ,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("sales");

                    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject employee = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(  MainActivity.this   );
                        TextView t1v = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                        t1v.setText(employee.getString("saletype"));
                        // ....
                        stk.addView(tbrow);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
});

mQueue.add(request);
```

Debugger keep throwing me exception :

> http://192.168.1.13/backendapi/api/api.php?apicall=getsale 0x676929be
>   NORMAL null

This code is working with some online api links but why not with my local ?

Note:

I added to my Manifes

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

P.S My first android project

Edit : Postman SS

[image]

Comment: headers are missing maybe.?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi no headers check Postman SS

Comment: Are you trying from an emulator or physical device ? Try to open that ip from the browser of the emulator to see if it can be reached. Probably it wont as the emulator has different network settings than your typical web environment

Comment: @113408 running on physical device :( . Can't set emulator on my laptop

Comment: Can you confirm that you can actually access the ip address from your physical device ? It will narrow down the problem

Comment: I disconnected the cable and tried to access to this api link and got error: You don't have permission to access on this server

Comment: @programerAnel have a look at my solution it will work now, hope so.!

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi actually the problem was i couldn't access due to my configuration on waamp : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/resolvedforbidden-you-dont-have-permission-access-server-elkial

Comment: try one thing generate wifi from some other device and then connect your system and mobile with that wifi and then run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

params were missing.

**API** : http://192.168.1.13/backendapi/api/api.php

I hope it will work now.

```
   @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }){
                            @Override
                            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                                Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
                                parameters.put("apicall","getsale");

                                return parameters;
                            }

                        };
```